# Derive host from the URL in LUA

Tags: lua

I have following URL.

```
http://localhost:4000/path?query=foo
http://localhost:4000/
http://localhost
http://localhost/
```

All I want is to return the `host` part. To be honest I do not care about the URL like this

```
 http://localhost:abcd/
 http://localhost:abcd/path?query=foo
```

because it's is guaranteed to correct URL.

I somehow manage to derive some pattern for it on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/orgRpqTD4C)

But this involves lookahead technique how do I apply lookahead technique. 
Which look like this

```
^https?:\/\/(.+)(?=[\/|$])
```

but there are 2 problems

- Lookahead technique does not work with `lua` match
- The regex is not full proof at least for the following `http://localhost` (notice the slash missing at the end)

So this is my question.

How do I solve this?

Comment: `s:match("://(.-)%f[:/%z]")`

Comment: does not include port number..

Comment: `s:match("://(.-)%f[/%z]")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to pattern matching is avoiding special cases, such as optional delimiters. Appending `/` to the string simplifies the task.

Try this code:

```
function host(s)
    return (s.."/"):match("://(.-)/")
end

function test(s)
    print(s,host(s))
end

test"http://localhost:4000/path?query=foo"
test"http://localhost:4000/"
test"http://localhost"
test"http://localhost/"
```

Comment: Does not include port number .. `http://localhost:4000/path?query=foo` only return localhost whereas i need `localhost:4000`

Comment: @Ratatouille, fixed.